# Wikipedia Images don't show up in browsers

Tags: google-chrome, images, opera, internet-explorer-8

It's a weird issue with [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org) which had left me frustrated.
When I go to wikipedia, with different browsers ( IE8, Chrome3, Opera10 ) no image in the site will show up.
Even right-clicking the image to ( show, save, open in new tab/window ) will return nothing except when open in new tab/window I'll get a black horizontal line across the page.
All my browsing across the web goes flawlessly, and every image in every site show up normally except in the wikipedia site.
I have win7 ultimate with all updates.

Comment: do you have ad block installed?

Comment: Are you able to open http://upload.wikimedia.org/favicon.ico ?  It's possible the domain doesn't resolve for some reason

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's something wrong with your hosts file?
Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts with notepad. What does it contain?

Otherwise try a different DNS provider, like Google or OpenDNS. Run the [GRC DNS benchmark](https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm) utility and change your DNS provider. That might help you access the images.

Comment: I opened the "hosts" file with MS word and found two addresses: one is about adobe.com and the other is upload.wikimedia.org. I deleted both and saved the file. Then the problem was solved!